# getmap error on Google Maps in a fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I try some Code with a Map in a fragemt.
It works but the Map ID didnt found. 
I get the warning that getMap is deprecated.

[image]

```
public class MapsActivity extends Fragment {

MapView mMapView;
private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // inflat and return the layout
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container,
            false);

    mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    mMapView.onResume();// needed to get the map to display immediately

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    googleMap = mMapView.getMap();
    // latitude and longitude
    double latitude = 17.385044;
    double longitude = 78.486671;
```

Comment: deprecation is not an error it's a warning

Comment: you have to implement OnMapReadyCallback and initializemap in onMapReady.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The getMap() method in MapView and MapFragment is now deprecated in
>   favor of the new getMapAsync() method.

Google provided [sample code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#add_map_code) for this:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
    implements OnMapReadyCallback {
...
}
```

and when initializing fragment:

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

when map is ready, you callback will be called

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
        .title("Marker"));
}
```

Comment: Perhapse someone can help me i am a absolut beginner.
So sorry if my Questions are stupid.

But where must i declare the mapFragment in the Mainactivity or the Mapsactivity ?

Answer (score 0):

Please one try to change the app:gradle because the getMap() helps some versions like
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0'

then try to sync the code again!